# Apply multiple times a function to new arrays

Tags: r, arrays, recursion, iteration

I have an array (say having 1000 elements) and a *function* that calculates two parameters on the array.

If the first parameter is 1 and the second 400, I then take 2 sub-arrays.
The first will have 400 elements, the second 600 elements.

On those new arrays I apply the function and repeat until the function outputs 0 on all sub arrays for all the parameters. I can have mant iterations.

I am wondering how to do this efficently in R.

[image]

The array exists at the beginning.

Here is an example code:

```
myfunc<-function(array) {
  random<-runif(1)
  result<-c(random,as.integer(random*length(array)))
}

data<-rnorm(2500,1000,50)
values<-myfunc(data)
# now I apply myfunc on the data
# If values[1] is smaller than 0.5, I stop
# if values[1] is larger, I generate two separate sub-arrays
if (values[1]>0.5){
first_array<-myfunc(data[1:values[2]])
second<-myfunc(data[values[2]:length(data)])
}
# And then on the first array, I apply myfunc and so on
```

Comment: are you trying to run a function on an array that already exists, or are you trying to create a new array? Some example data and expected output would go a long way here.

Comment: Thanks. I just have updated the post